# Why does multiprocessing work on Django runserver and not on ngnix uwsgi?

Tags: django, http, python-3.x, uwsgi

I have a Django 1.6 using python3.3 application which receives an http request, does short term work, starts a new process and returns in a matter of 2 seconds. The process typically takes 50-60 seconds at which time it writes that the data is free on the data base where a timed ajax call can retrieve the data and update the clint web page.

This works perfectly on the Django development runserver.

When I deploy the application on ngnix uwsgi the quick response is delayed for 50-60 seconds and appears in tandem with the completion of the process.

I logged the time between entering the view and just before sending the response and it was 1-2 seconds.

I checked the packets with wireshark and all communication ceases for the duration of the process i.e 50-60 seconds.

in the uwsgi .ini file I used processes=3

I would be grateful for a solution or a line of investigation.

the .ini file:

> [uwsgi], chdir=/nnnhn/, module=wsgi, #master=True, pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid, vacuum=True, max-requests=5000, daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi.log, socket=/tmp/uwsgi.sock, uid=hhm, processes=3, pythonpath=/csghgfh/doo

the process spawning code:

```
process=multiprocessing.Process(target=Util.processImage1, args=(processUtil, img_full_path, snapshot.pk, process_pk, db_name, process_table_name))
process.start()
```

the relevant spawned code:

```
def processImage1(self, img_full_path, snapshot_pk, process_pk, db_name, process_table_name):
    connection.close()
    print('')
    print('I think I just closed th db connection connection')
    print('')
    print('processImage1:', datetime.now())
    print('process_pk: ', process_pk)
    sys.stdout.flush()

    try:
        con = psycopg2.connect(host = 'a', database=db_name, user='a') 
        cur = con.cursor()
```

Comment: you mind adding your uwsgi.ini and the code that spawns the proc?

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in the (probably) most important page of the uWSGI docs: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html

When you fork() the process, the new one will inherit the connection descriptor. You have to close it in the new forked process, or you can add the --close-on-exec option to force it automatically

Comment: I had a problem with the cloned connections so I opened a new connection using psycop2 on the cloned process and it works with the runserver. Do you think that the view doesn't return the http response  if the connection is still exists in the cloned process?

Comment: I tried closing the connection thus in the cloned process connection.close() and it still does not work

Comment: it is not the connection with psycopg2 that causes the issue, is the connection between the client and uWSGI that get inherited in the new children. Until you do not close it in both, the conneciton with the client (read: your webserver) will remain open. If you do not want to use --close-on-exec you can close the file descriptor returned by uwsgi.connection_fd()

Comment: What do you meen by read: webserver? where should I use --close-on-exec?

Comment: from the uWSGI point of view the webserver is the client. --close-on-exec is a uWSGI option

Comment: I tried using the option with and without the = sign to no avail. I am beginning to think I have to create an independent daemon to do background jobs with uwsgi.

Comment: @ManishGupta I ended up circumventing the problem using a stateless pattern i.e. I wrote the job to a data base. another application monitored and did the job and when it finished it changes the status. meanwhile the app busy poled the status. I think Django is to constrictive for anything more than run of the mill web apps; automation kills creativity

Comment: @RubberDuck Thanks for the tip. I too wrote the jobs to a database and wrote a cron to read those jobs from database and execute them.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use **djcelery** for the asynchronous tasks. You also get the tasks queue, scheduled execution, monitoring, etc.

Comment: I would like to avoid the overhead learning curve and dependencies which come with celery.