# python process takes time to start in django project running on nginx and uwsgi

Tags: python, django, nginx, process, uwsgi

I am starting a process using python's multiprocessing module. The process is invoked by a post request sent in a django project. When I use development server (python manage.py runserver), the post request takes no time to start the process and finishes immediately.

I deployed the project on production using nginx and uwsgi.

Now when i send the same post request, it takes around 5-7 minutes to complete that request. It only happens with those post requests where I am starting a process. Other post requests work fine.

What could be reason for this delay? And How can I solve this?

Comment: When you run the code in production, does the processing succeed? i.e. is your deployment configuration incorrect such that it takes 5-7 minutes for network timeouts/retries and then fails?

Comment: I have set the timeout for requests for 900 seconds in nginx configuration. So they dont timeout . They are just taking a lot of time. And there is no error occuring.

Comment: Where is the slowdown occurring? On starting up the new process or waiting on its results? If the latter, does the POST request need to remain open while processing is happening on the process or can it just return immediately and perform the processing in the background? Generally with interactive applications there would not be any blocking as processing times vary depending on load and would do either a call back on the result or polling to retrieve results.

Comment: No. The post request just starts the process and returns. on returning the request is completed and a notification comes up on the frontend. The process started is independent of the application and just hits an API. So I dont think the POST request is waiting for any result. Also in dev server the whole request + process is working fine and the POST gets completed immediately.

Comment: So the slowdown is in getting results from the spun process? You mentioned it's hitting an API, how long does that call take locally vs in production and how long in total does the processing take?

Comment: That depends from user to user. So If a user has say 2000 products the script will take around 30-40 mins to finish and will result in a timeout. Also in local development environment as I said before the POST request only invokes the process and returns. it doesn't wait for the process to finish neither does it wait for the results. The only purpose of the POST request is to start the background process and return.

Comment: Could you, please, post relevant code? e.g. the view

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929310/why-does-multiprocessing-work-on-django-runserver-and-not-on-ngnix-uwsgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround (Don't know if it will qualify as an answer).
I wrote the background process as a job in database and used a cronjob to check if I have any job pending and if there are any the cron will start a background process for that job and will exit.

The cron will run every minute so that there is not much delay. This helped in improved performance as it helped me execute heavy tasks like this to run separate from main application.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the background processing needs to be started outside the WSGI application module.

In WSGI, a python webapp process is started to handle requests, number of which vary depending on configuration. If this process spawns a new process that will block the WSGI process from handling new requests, making the server block and wait for it to finish before handling new requests.

What I would suggest is you use a shared queue in the WSGI application module to feed into a process started *outside* the WSGI application module. Something like the below. This will start one new processor for each WSGI process outside the webapp module so as not to block requests.

`your_app/webapp.py`:

```
from . import bg_queue
def post():
    # Webapp POST code here
    bg_queue.add(<task data>)
```

`your_app/processor.py`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class Consumer(Process):
    def __init__(self, input_q):
        self.input_q = input_q

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task_data = input_q.get()
            <process data>
```

`your_app/__init__.py`:

```
from .processor import Consumer
bg_queue = Queue()

consumer = Consumer(bg_queue)
consumer.daemon = True
consumer.start()
```